# Run multiple SQL UPDATE statements on submit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-update

I have several update statements that need to be run upon submit being clicked.  I can run a single update but I am struggling to figure out how to run all of them prior to refreshing the page.  Here is what I have tried but I am getting an error on my closing of the connection which did not occur when running a single statement.

```
if ($conn->query($usqlMC)  == True) {
if ($conn->query($usqlSCn)  == True) {
    if ($conn->query($usqlSCv)  == True) {
        if ($conn->query($usqlTn)  == True) {
            if ($conn->query($usqlTurl)  == True) {
                if ($conn->query($usqlTv)  == True) {
                    header("location: http://localhost/phpkiosk/mc1.php");
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am sure this is completely wrong so any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!!

ADDED ERROR MESSAGE

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp2\www\phpKiosk\mc1.php on line 1196

Again I receive no error when I run:

```
if ($conn->query($usqlMC)  == True) {
    header("location: http://localhost/phpkiosk/mc1.php");
}
```

WORKING SOLUTION

using Chris85's suggestion I was able to get this to work:

```
if ($conn->query($usqlMC) === TRUE && 
   $conn->query($usqlSCn) ===TRUE &&
   $conn->query($usqlSCv) ===TRUE &&
   $conn->query($usqlTn) ===TRUE &&
   $conn->query($usqlTurl) ===TRUE &&
   $conn->query($usqlTv) ===TRUE) {
   header("location: http://localhost/phpkiosk/mc1.php");
   } 
}
```

Comment: What is the error? You could have all those conditions in one `if` with `&&`s.

Comment: @chris85 I have updated my question to include the error message

Comment: That error usually means one of the control blocks isn't closed. Is that your exact code? Here, make it way simpler; `if ($conn->query($usqlMC)  == True &&  $conn->query($usqlSCn)  == True && $conn->query($usqlSCv)  == True && $conn->query($usqlTn)  == True && $conn->query($usqlTurl)  == True && $conn->query($usqlTv)  == True) {`.

Comment: Redirect when all queries execute if this is required thancu cant use like that u must need to use &&

Comment: U r getting parse error becuase one of them condition false.

Comment: @chris85 I updated my code using yours and I am still getting the same error...

Comment: @devpro shouldnt it just do nothing since I dont have an else catch written in?

Comment: As Chris suggest use && still getting error?

Comment: If you updated with my code then the issue is another control block not being closed. The line number is irrelevant with this error because that is where the file ended, it has no idea what you forgot to close.

Comment: Yes same error even after switching to 
&&

Comment: As @Chris85 said I am adding one thing if u r using only one condition your code works fine right.. So debug line by line test with two fields and three so on.. U will get the idea

Comment: I ended up deleting the entire block and adding it line by line and checking after each line.  There must have been a syntax error that was not being picked up because now its working using what @chris85 suggested.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Cool... Good work. Its best practice to debug step by step. :)

Comment: @devpro I know.  I am knew to coding and tend to get a little excitable and get ahead of myself.  Thanks for the reminder though :)

Comment: I'll post that as an answer so the thread is resolved. Note in your update there are two `}`s but only one opening, so that could have been the issue, something else is open.

Comment: @chris85 Yes I see.  The second is required for the code to work as it is the  closing for the if submit condition but for this example it should have been left out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need separate checks it is easier keep all conditions in one `if`, that also simplifies the control blocks opening and closing.

So this:

```
if ($conn->query($usqlMC)  == True &&  
    $conn->query($usqlSCn)  == True && 
    $conn->query($usqlSCv)  == True && 
    $conn->query($usqlTn)  == True && 
    $conn->query($usqlTurl)  == True && 
    $conn->query($usqlTv)  == True) {
          header("location: http://localhost/phpkiosk/mc1.php");
}
```

should perform the same for you but only require one control block.

Also with the

> unexpected end of file

error never believe the line number. That is just where the file is ending not where the error is. PHP has no way of knowing where a block was meant to be closed.

For example:

```
<?php
if (1==1) {
echo 'this is true';
echo 'I also want to do this';
echo 'I meant to close here';
echo 'code done';
```

would throw error on line 6 but the error is actually on line 4/5 where I failed to close the `if`.

Comment: @craig-howell accept this answer otherwise people will think this is not closed

Comment: The checkbox is green but it isn't showing up as answered when I search...

Comment: @CraigHowell Your page might be cached, it is showing as answered for me.